# How do I use AfxOleGetMessageFilter in a VB .NET program?

Tags: .net, com

We have a program that calls a long-running (SolidWorks) API function. After a while, we get an error dialog saying that "the COM server is busy...". We've done some research and have found that you can control this by using a bit of C++ code similar to:

```
  COleMessageFilter *pFilter = AfxOleGetMessageFilter();
          if(pFilter)
          {
              pFilter->SetMessagePendingDelay(60000);
              pFilter = NULL;
          }
```

Problem is, we're ignorant on the C++ front and want to use VB.NET. We dug around and it turns out AfxOleGetMessageFilter comes from some MFC library. So my question is: is there some way we can achieve this call from VB.NET w/o getting into MFC? Is AfxOleGetMessageFilter a wrapper around some other WIN32API call that we can just DECLARE and call ourselves? Are there alternatives we should be pursuing?

I have one answer that suggests I implement the .NET IMessageFilter interface, but since that interface has only one seemingly unrelated method I'm still stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse `COleMessageFilter` from MFC this way.

You have to [implement `IMessageFilter` in VB.Net](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d3cdf3fa-cbd9-4690-818d-bfa386dfd598)

Comment: I don't see how IMessageFilter can be used to extend or suspend the timeout, it only implements one method called PreFilterMessage which doesn't seem to do any good. ???